# Convert Rows Category into Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of categories as follow.

```
mappingCategory = ["Animal", "Plant", "Animal", "Human", "Plant"]
```

| Index | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Animal |
| 1 | Plant |
| 2 | Animal |
| 3 | Human |
| 4 | Plant |

I want to convert the array into 2D array where the column is unique category (order by alphabet) and the rows show what category is in that row like this.

```
mappingCategory = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

| Index | Animal | Human | Plant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I can build my own function to convert it, but is there any python build in function I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), as follows:

If you have a dataframe column named `Category`, use:

```
df['Category'].str.get_dummies()
```

Or, if you do it directly from the array of categories:

```
mappingCategory = ["Animal", "Plant", "Animal", "Human", "Plant"]

pd.Series(mappingCategory).str.get_dummies()
```

**Output:**

```
   Animal  Human  Plant
0       1      0      0
1       0      0      1
2       1      0      0
3       0      1      0
4       0      0      1
```